# Toggling iOS Bar Button identifier (Play/Pause) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, toggle, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonsystemitem

I know similar questions have been asked and answered in the past. However, I seem to have trouble with executing a simple act of toggling the left bar button from Play to Pause.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func toggleButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "someFakeAction"), animated: true)
}

func someFakeAction() {
    println("Button pressed")
}
```

When I tap the Play button, there is a quick fading animation and then the Play button returns. The function someFakeAction is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Declare UIBarButtonItem globally so that you can access it later. lets call it `playPauseButton`
2. Declare a boolean variable globally for keeping track if it is playing or paused, lets call it `isPlaying`.
3. From viewDidLoad init `isPlaying = true`, and playPauseButton with action `pauseIt` and set it as `leftBarButtonItem`.
4. if button is pressed in `pauseIt` method init `isPlaying = false`, initialize `playPauseButton` with a action `playIt` and set it to `leftBarButtonItem`.
5. in `playIt` set `isPlaying = true` again and init the `playPauseButton` with action `pauseIt`.